# Check if string contains any of the specified words and remove them

Tags: php

I have a variable that I'm trying to check whether it contains a set of specific words. If it contains any of those words, they should be removed.

The code I've tried is:

```
$title = 'Help my title';    
$array = array("help","test","trying");
    if(0 < count(array_intersect(explode(' ', strtolower($title)), $array))){
      $titlenew = str_replace($array, "", $title);
    }
```

My expectation is that the above would return:

```
my title
```

If it could be case insensitive too, that would be great - although it's not my priority.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [`str_ireplace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php):

```
$title = 'Help my title';    
$array = array("help","test","trying");
echo str_ireplace($array, '', $title); // my title
```

Comment: This would also replace words within other words, i.e. "self-help service" would become "self- service" with this example.

Comment: @RonniEgeriis OP clearly said **if variable contains any of those words**

Comment: @RahilWazir I can see now that it can be interpreted in two ways. In any case, I would just point out a gotcha with this solution for future reference, in case anyone who only want to replace whole words stumble upon this question.

Comment: @RahilWazir I don't agree as the question does not clearly state whether or not to replace words within words. I just hope to clarify any confusion with my comment.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably do this with regular expressions:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\b(word1|word2)\b/i', '', $str);
```

`\b` is a word boundary: https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php

Comment: @RahilWazir Because e.g. `str_ireplace` would also replace "test" in "thisisatest".